# Al crear una tabla temporal en MySQL y asignar datos de otra tabla es necesario especificar los tipos de datos?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Tengo una duda, estoy usando el siguiente query:
Create temporary table tbl as
Select * from bd.tbl2 where fecha < '2018-09-08'

El asunto es que no comprendo aún si al crear una tabla temporal y asignarle datos de otra tabla inmediatamente, es necesario especificar que tipo de datos contendrá cada columna?

Answer (score 1):

No, segun la documentación el campo toma el tipo de dato segun su valor asignado ya que la tabla solo existe durante la sesion;

> Puede usar la palabra clave TEMPORARY cuando crea una tabla. Una tabla
>   TEMPORAL solo es visible para la sesión actual y se descarta
>   automáticamente cuando se cierra la sesión. Esto significa que dos
>   sesiones diferentes pueden usar el mismo nombre de tabla temporal sin
>   conflicto entre ellas o con una tabla existente no TEMPORAL del mismo
>   nombre. (La tabla existente está oculta hasta que se descarta la tabla
>   temporal). Para crear tablas temporales, debe tener el privilegio
>   CREAR TABLAS TEMPORALES.

a tu codigo yo le agregaria lo siguiente;

```
  CREATE temporary TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl AS 
  SELECT * 
  FROM   bd.tbl2 
  WHERE  fecha < '2018-09-08'
```

Documentacion:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html